# Java Manifest File Codebase attribute

Tags: java, file, attributes, manifest, codebase

I am currently writing a few Ant build scripts for some JAR files, for use with the updated Java security settings as of Java 1.7.0_51.  I have run into a problem with the codebase attribute; this attribute apparently requires the exact URL that the code will be stored and accessed via, however this not known at the time of JAR packaging.  We build and create our JAR files and then sign them.  Is there any way to specify the codebase attribute at a later time without having to unpack the JAR, modify the manifest, repackage the JAR and then re-sign?

I understand this is a long shot, I'm just looking for a little clarity on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a * in codebase or if you have a list of all of the supported URLs you can add all of them. [Manifest documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/manifest.html)